# Sharing a hard drive between two hosts, one at a time

Tags: linux, hard-drive, sata, linux-kernel, data-transfer

I have a large hard drive in my desktop computer. My laptop has an eSata port. Sometimes, I power-up the desktop PC, without booting, just to get juice flowing into the hard drive so that I can connect it to the laptop with an esata2cable and sync data (works OK). At other times, I want the hard drive fully connected to the desktop computer (both power and data(SATA)).

Assuming I run the desktop PC's OS from a different hard drive, is it safe to switch the data cable between *SATA_to_SATA_to_Desktop* and *SATA_to_eSATA_to_LAPTOP* while the Desktop PC is on, running an OS from the other hard drive?

What would be the protocol for doing this apart from unmounting all partitions and deactivating all Logical Volume groups.

Edit:
As a matter of fact, I've hot-swapped  between these two a couple of times. What I did was unmount all partitions, deactivate all LV groups, power off the hard drive via the power-off interface provided by `gnome-disks` (don't know what it does at a lower level) and suspend the Desktop OS before swapping the data cable, at which point I resumed the OS to get power flowing into the hard drive. It worked fine, but I'm not sure if this couldn't lead to data corruption or hardware failure somewhere down to road or if I could do it safely even without the suspend-resume part (which I assumed might help, but I'm not sure).

Comment: As I wrote, it'e either SATA_to_SATA_to_Desktop or  SATA_to_eSATA_to_Laptop, so both.

Comment: I've never used NAS, but wouldn't that be limited to the max speed of my network link?

Comment: I have two cables SATA2SATA and SATA2eSATA.

Comment: @Ramhound SATA is not hot swap capable? [Wikipedia disagrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#Hotplug), and [so does the Linux kernel](https://web.archive.org/web/20090124023117/http://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Software_status#Hotplug_support) even from way back when [as well as now](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Software_status#Hotplug_support), stating that "Most SATA controllers are hotplug-capable, ... All SATA devices are hotplug-capable.". Note that "SATA controllers" refers to the controller card itself ("yank the card", not "yank the drive").

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - My original comment was wrong.  Since I feel like I am pulling teeth trying to get information.  I will allow somebody else to get the clarification what the user means by SATA2SATA.  I suspect he meants he is just using a normal SATA3 cable.

Comment: @Ramhound Your comment (since deleted) said that eSATA was hot plug capable and SATA was not hot plug capable. That seemed fairly specific to me, and also fairly readily demonstrably wrong.

Comment: I know what I said.  I then clarified it in a second comment.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments; they pointed me in the right direction, especially [Michael Kjörling's](https://superuser.com/users/53590/michael-kj%c3%b6rling) comment that SATA devices are hot-plug capable and most controllers should be too.

I've found this article: 
http://www.tuxradar.com/answers/570
which seems to give reasonable advice -- try the hot swap with the unmounting and all and watch kernel logs for possible errors.